# Microsoft Dynamics 2011 - Passing form fields to URL (iFrame)

Tags: java, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I am currently using MS CRM 2011 on-premise, with rollup 14, I have the below code which I'm trying to fire onload of a record, however I get the below exception:

```
function updateBingIFrame()
{
////get the name
var accountName = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("name").getValue();
//Check that there is a name
if (accountName)
{
////Update the IFrame
var bingIframe = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("IFRAME_Bing");
var newUrl = "http://www.bing.com/?q=" + encodeURIComponent(accountName);
bingIframe.setSrc(newUrl);
}
}
```

Unable to get value of the property 'setsrc':object is null or undefined

I believe 'setsrc' is no longer compatible with versions of CRM post rollup 12, can anyone supply with alternative code in order to get this to fire?

Answer (score 0):

I see no reference of `setSrc` in the code snippet that you have supplied. The only reference that you have is `getSrc`. Can you try changing the code and see if it works for you.

And just for the record `setSrc` was never deprecated (AFAIK), I'm also currently using this method in one of the implementations and we're on UR15.

If you still get the error can you provide some more details on it and we can work it through.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My apologies the code I uploaded should have been setSrc, I have updated the post to avoid confusion. I'm still experiencing the same problems:

“Unable to get value of the property 'setsrc':object is null or undefined”

I’m simply trying to pass on the field value of “Name” from the account form onto Bing search “onload” of a record in the account entity (through an iframe) http://www.bing.com/

Answer (score 0):

hi can you try this?

```
var iFrame = "IFRAME_Name";   
var Url = "http//www.stackoverflow.com";   
Xrm.Page.getControl(iFrame).setSrc(Url);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Dynamics CRM 2011 with rollup 14 installed, and 'setSrc' seems to work fine for me! Dynamics CRM 2013 also supports 'setSrc', so I don't why it wouldn't be compatible with CRM 2011 rollup 12.

I would suggest you to double check that you provided the correct name for the iFrame.